# Writing tests for a contract function that uses a struct

Tags: testing, struct

I have a contract that implements an interface which contains a struct that is used in both the arguments to a function as well as the return value.

```
// IContract.sol
interface IContract {
  struct Data {
    bytes32,
    address,
    uint32
  }

  function doSomething(Data inputData) external returns (Data memory);
}
```

```
// Contract.sol
contract Contract is IContract {
  function doSomething(Data inputData) external override return (Data memory) {
    ...
  }
}
```

In my `Contract.test.ts`, how do I create a `Data` instance to be used in the test's call to `doSomething`? Do I need to import the `Data` struct from `IContract.sol` somehow? I can't seem to type the variable the way I expect to.

```
// Contract.test.ts
...
beforeEach(async () => {
  const factory = await ethers.getContractFactory("ContractName");
  contract = await factory.deploy();
  await contract.deployed();
});

it("should test doSomething", async () => {
  contract.Data mockData = ... // this does not work
  expect(contract.doSomething(mockData)).to.be...;
});
...
```